# Replace collections' defaultdict by a normal dict with setdefault

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I often used `collections.defaultdict` to be able to append an element to `d[key]` without having to initialize it first to `[]` (benefit: you don't need to do: `if key not in d: d[key] = []`):

```
import collections, random
d = collections.defaultdict(list)  
for i in range(100):
    j = random.randint(0,20)
    d[j].append(i)  # if d[j] does not exist yet, initialize it to [], so we can use append directly
```

Now I realize we can simply use a normal `dict` and `setdefault`:

```
import random
d = {}
for i in range(100):
    j = random.randint(0,20)
    d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
```

**Question: when using a `dict` whose values are lists, is there a good reason to use a `collections.defaultdict` instead of the second method (using a simple `dict` and `setdefault`), or are they purely equivalent?**

Comment: Please @downvoter, could you add a note about how to improve the question (formatting? wording? etc.) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` is generally more performant, it is optimised exactly for this task and C-implemented. However, you should use `dict.setdefault` if you want accessing an absent key in your resulting dictionary to result in a `KeyError` rather than inserting an empty list. This is the most important practical difference.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by Chris_Rands, I want to further emphasize that a primary reason to use `defaultdict` is if you want key accesses to always succeed, and to insert the default value if there was none.
This can be for any reason, and a completely valid one is the convenience of being able to use `[]` instead of having to call `dict.setdefault` before every access.

Also note that `key in default_dict` will still return `False` if that key has never been accessed before, so you can still check for existence of keys in a `defaultdict` if necessary. This allows appending to the lists without checking for their existence, but also checking for the existence of the lists if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When using `defaultdict` you have a possibility to do inplace addition:

```
import collections, random
d = collections.defaultdict(list)  
for i in range(100):
    j = random.randint(0,20)
    d[j] += [i]
```

There is no equivalent construction like `d.setdefault(j, []) += [i]`, it gives `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`.